# JQuery form submit not calling success

Tags: javascript, jquery

After click on submit `beforeSend:` works but it does not call `success:` also there is no console error . The data also submit to database correctly ! Then why it not call the `success:` . Please Help

```
$(function() {
    //hang on event of form with id=ticketForm
    $("#ticketForm").submit(function(e) {
        //prevent Default functionality
        e.preventDefault();
        //get the action-url of the form
        var actionurl = e.currentTarget.action;
        var form = $('#ticketForm');
        var submit = $('#submite');

        $.ajax({
            url: actionurl,
            type: "POST",
            data: $("#ticketForm").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(e) {
                submit.html("Booking....");
            },
            success: function(e) {
                submit.html("Booking Completed !");
                //get the message from booking.php and show it.
                $(".alert").removeClass("hide");
                var msg = $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: actionurl,
                    async: false
                }).responseText;
                document.getElementById("success-message").innerHTML = msg;
                setTimeout(function() { // wait for 3 secs(2)
                    location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)
                }, 3000);
            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Console Message**

```
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "<strong>Seat Booked Successfully</strong>", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
```

Comment: Your console message is from `error`, the response must be a valid JSON.

Comment: why do you use second ajax call? what result do you return for the first one? does "Booking Completed !" get displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AJAX call settings you set `dataType` to `json`, but in return you provide a string.

> dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)) The
>   type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is
>   specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the
>   response

So, you have two solutions:

1. Provide a valid JSON in response
2. Do not ask for JSON by changing your `dataType` value (to `html`), or by removing it.

Comment: @skokaljic you are right after removing the `dataType` it call the success but the form submit 2 times or i found 2 row on data base :(

Comment: Your code submits it once, please clean your data and check it again.

Comment: when I remove `setTimeout()` section from the `success:` then the data saved one time on database else save 2 times.

Comment: Reloading the page should have nothing with form submission... you are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

In a Ajax call 'dataType' attributes means what data format can be expect from client(browser). As per error message server is returning 'string' instead 'json'.

But on the other hand, given ajax call is expecting json data to be returned by backend server. Either provide a
valid JSON in response or change datatype to html.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. As you are redirecting page in success you need to use 
e.preventDefault(); // to prevent page refresh

after the ajax call or

return false; // to prevent page refresh

Something like this :

```
$(function() {
//hang on event of form with id=ticketForm
$("#ticketForm").submit(function(e) {
//prevent Default functionality
e.preventDefault();
//get the action-url of the form
var actionurl = e.currentTarget.action;
var form = $('#ticketForm');
var submit = $('#submite');     


$.ajax({
        url: actionurl,
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#ticketForm").serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function(e) {
          submit.html("Booking....");
        },
        success: function(e) {
            submit.html("Booking Completed !");
            //get the message from booking.php and show it.
            $( ".alert" ).removeClass( "hide" );
            var msg = $.ajax({type: "GET", url: actionurl, async: false}).responseText; 
            document.getElementById("success-message").innerHTML = msg;
            setTimeout(function(){// wait for 3 secs(2)
            location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)
            }, 3000); 
        },

        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
});
return false;     e.preventDefault();  //any one of this options to prevent page refresh after ajax call
});
});
```

Comment: and my question is why it not call the `success:` but it call 'beforeSend:`

Comment: I had similar problem. please try my suggestion once and let me know if it works. Its weird but it worked for me. :)